# Finding words with an apostrophe in it

Tags: hive

I have a column that has values like `i'm`, `it's`, `don't`, etc.  So, one record will have just `i'm`, another record with have the word `don't` only, etc.

I need to write `SQL` that retrieves these values, but what I've done hasn't worked.

For example, If I write 
`select * from testtable1 where column1 like 'i''m'`
 I don't get results.  Am I missing a character that I need to put in?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from testtable1 where column1 like "%'%";
```

Can you just use double quotes?

Answer (score 0):

try rlike to fetch the rows from table like this.

```
hive> select * from temp;
OK
1   i'm
2   i don't
3   hello
```

Fetch the record that match the rlike condition.

```
hive> select * from temp where value rlike '\'';
OK
1   i'm
2   i don't
Time taken: 0.376 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)
```